# Error while updating property 'defaultSrc' of a view managed by: RCTImageView (android pre-launch report)

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I'm seeing a crash related to a possible memory leak due to images on my react native app.  I can't reproduce, but every time I deploy to the play store, one of my pre-launch devices (the Moto Z running android 7.0) crashes with this error (full stack trace below!).

```
com.facebook.react.bridge.JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException: Error while updating property 'defaultSrc' of a view managed by: RCTImageView
```

I can't repro myself ,and consistently see this crash for JUST the Moto Z (the other 10 devices work fine).  Some users in prod have reported crashing, with this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeExceptionDisplayListCanvas.java:229
Canvas: trying to draw too large(345855600bytes) bitmap.
```

These both started happening around the same time (after a major redesign), and seem to be connected.

I've tried enabling `largeHeap` and disabling `hardwareAcceleration` in the Android manifest.  I've also updated to the latest version of React-Native 0.60.5.

Here are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "apollo-cache-redux": "^0.1.0",
    "apollo-client": "^2.2.7",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.1",
    "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.8",
    "apollo-link-error": "^1.0.9",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.3",
    "apollo-link-redux": "^0.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "bugsnag-react-native": "^2.10.2",
    "create-react-native-app": "^1.0.0",
    "global": "^4.3.2",
    "graphql": "^0.13.2",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.8.0",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.7.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.13",
    "moment": "^2.21.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-apollo": "^2.1.3",
    "react-native": "0.60.5",
    "react-native-auth0": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-autolink": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-fontawesome": "^5.7.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.10",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-simple-store": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.3.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "prettier": "^1.11.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
```

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.parade, PID: 11503
com.facebook.react.bridge.JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException: Error while updating property 'defaultSrc' of a view managed by: RCTImageView
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateViewProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:98)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackViewManagerSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:131)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:51)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager.updateProperties(ViewManager.java:46)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.createView(NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:268)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$CreateViewOperation.execute(UIViewOperationQueue.java:198)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.dispatchPendingNonBatchedOperations(UIViewOperationQueue.java:1036)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.doFrameGuarded(UIViewOperationQueue.java:1007)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedFrameCallback.java:29)
    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:172)
    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame(ChoreographerCompat.java:84)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:869)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:616)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateViewProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:83)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 614854412 byte allocation with 8448244 free bytes and 499MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(VMRuntime.java)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(BitmapFactory.java)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1152)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:724)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:575)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:767)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:738)
    at com.facebook.react.views.imagehelper.ResourceDrawableIdHelper.getResourceDrawable(ResourceDrawableIdHelper.java:78)
    at com.facebook.react.views.image.ReactImageView.setDefaultSource(ReactImageView.java:377)
    at com.facebook.react.views.image.ReactImageManager.setDefaultSource(ReactImageManager.java:94)
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score -1):

Please provide snippet code. Usually this errors appears when setting 'defaultSource' and providing incorrect uri or path to the Image component (but only in release builds as React Native docs states because the defaultSource is being ignored on debug builds:

> [Note: On Android, the default source prop is ignored on debug builds.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image)

)